# How to dump the phonetic dictionary with espeak

Tags: machine-learning, cmusphinx

I have been trying to create a grapheme to phoneme dictionary for cmusphinx using espeak but when I choose compile from the menu and choose compile dictionary it says compiled successfully but I can't find the .dic file anywhere.

Please advise on where to find my compiled files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dictionary compilation is unrelated to phonetic dictionary dump. You need to use -x option instead to display phones for the list of the input words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary compilation is unrelated to phonetic dictionary dump. You need to use -x option instead to display phones for the list of the input words.

First create a list of words in your language. Then install espeak-ng and run

```
 echo "tuần" | espeak -v vi -x --sep=" "
```

It will output the entry for the word:

```
 tuần t[ w '@2 n _|
```

You need to clean this entry from special symbols like ' or _ and leave just phonemes, that will be:

```
 tuần t w @2 n
```